# OO vs FP | imperative vs FP

Tags: functional-programming

I often come across comparisons between object-oriented and functional programming, and between imperative and functional programming. "Object-oriented" and "imperative" are two distinct terms which, in my understanding, have nothing to do with each other. Still, they are both compared to functional programming. What is the relationship between object-oriented and imperative programming that motivates such comparisons?

Comment: Impossible to say without the context.

Comment: Would probably fit better on cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simply, that mainstream OO-programming (i.e. Java, C#) is a sub-category of imperative programming.

Here is a rough chart:

```
                   progamming
                   /        \
              declarative   imperative
                 /    \          /   \ 
         functional    \        OO   procedural  
                       logic 
                       (prolog)
```

In declarative programming, you say what it is you want to compute. Say we want to compute the length of a linked list:

- The length of an empty list is 0
- The length of a nonempty list is one more than the length of the tail of that list.

In imperative programming, you basically manipulate memory in a certain order:

```
int length = 0;              // put starting value in memory
while (!list.isEmpty()) {
   length++;                 // update memory
   list = list.next();       // update list pointer for next iteration
}
// result is in memory location associated with length
```

So, the proper comparisions would be:

- imperative vs. declarative
- OO vs functional

Comment: On the other hand, OO concepts can be applied to imperative, functional, and declarative programming as code encapsulation and code reuse concerns are common to any programming paradigm. This results in an alternative view where imperative, functional, and declarative paradigms are at the same level with the OO paradigm intercepting them and at a higher level. You can easily find languages representatives of all three main programming paradigms with well integrated interpretations/materializations of OO concepts.

Comment: @PauloMoura It's not like code encapsulation/reuse are OO inventions. But you are right, concepts and ideas float either directions, which is a good thing.